# Android TV app rejected - not navigable using a 5-way DPad controller

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-tv

I'm having issue with publishing Android app for Android TV.
We have tested the app on Android TV, everything is working fine. But the app is constantly rejected by Google Play with an explanation:

*Your app is not navigable using a 5-way DPad controller. App functionality should be navigable using 5-way D-pad controls.*

Did anyone had similar problem issue, and if yes, how did you resolve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can yous post your Android Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you should check that your app supports navigation with 5-way D-pad. Did you test your application with TV set or emulator?
Users have to use the app with TV remote controller. Maybe you don't have focused  states for views or users can't select some button with TV remote controller